# Принимать на ввод только положительные числа

Tags: c++, qt, валидация

Как сделать чтобы ввести в *QLineEdit* можно было только строго положительные вещественные числа?
Пытаюсь использовать для этого вот такой *QDoubleValidator*

```
QDoubleValidator* validator = new QDoubleValidator();
validator->setBottom(0);
```

Но он пропускает все неотрицательные числа, включая 0.

Comment: `validator->setBottom(1);` + `validator->setNotation(QDoubleValidator::StandardNotation);` ?

Comment: Так надо же не от одного, а от нуля, дробные числа тоже надо принимать

Comment: `setBottom` принимает double, поэтому `1` будет сконвертирован в double http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdoublevalidator.html#bottom-prop

Comment: 1 сконвертированная в double это 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
validator->setBottom(std::numeric_limits<double>::min());
```

Или, в зависимости от потребностей, `denorm_min()` или `epsilon()`.